# How to find the longest contiguous odd subsequence in Python?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

For example, my sequence is: `[2, 6, 8, 3, 9, 1, 5, 6, 1, 3, 5]` then the answer should be [3, 9, 1, 5] as there are two subsequences `[1, 3, 5]` and `[3, 9, 1, 5]`. The longest one should be returned as the answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your attempt so far? Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.groupby`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
l = [2, 6, 8, 3, 9, 1, 5, 6, 1, 3, 5]
final_list = []
for i in l:
   new_l = []
   if i%2 == 0:
      final_list.append(new_l)
      new_l = []
   else:
       new_l.append(i)

print(max(final_list, key=len))
```

Output:

```
[3, 9, 1, 5]
```

Comment: I do not really get why you perform a nested `for` loop. Right now you make it an *O(n^2)* algorithm. A single pass is sufficient. Furthermore because of the `[i+1:]`, you ignore the first element.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much :) Just a correction: the first `new_l` assignment should be above for loop else it prints an empty list. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following complicated one-liner:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

max(map(list,map(itemgetter(1),filter(itemgetter(0),groupby(data,key=lambda x:x&1)))),key=len)
```

with `data` the input list.

Let's first split this up into several parts:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

tmp = groupby(data,key=lambda x:x&1)  # group by even-odd bursts
tmp = filter(itemgetter(0),tmp)       # filter only bursts of odd numbers
tmp = map(itemgetter(1),tmp)          # obtain the slice of numbers
tmp = map(list,tmp)                   # convert them to lists
result = max(tmp,key=len)             # get the list with the largest length
```

This algorithm runs in *O(n)* since it performs a fixed number of passes (due to *lazyness* it only scans the list once actually) over the `data` list. All checks are *O(1)* (for every element-check), or *O(k)* for every burst (with *k* the length of that burst).

You can rewrite the above in a less functional style with (kudos to [@PM2Ring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45264987/how-to-find-the-longest-contiguous-odd-subsequence-in-python/45265080#comment77493126_45265080)):

```
max((list(g) for k,g in groupby(data,key=lambda x:x&1) if k),key=len)
```

It is equivalent to the above, but less *pointfree* (that's a term in *functional programming*).

Comment: Yeah, ok. Personally, I wouldn't use `itemgetter` here, I'd just do `max((list(g) for k, g in groupby(a, key=lambda n: n % 2) if k), key=len)`

Comment: @PM2Ring: yes. That's probably more because of too much functional programming. The former is considered "more pointfree".